# Scalar subquery WHERE clause DATA STUDIO

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio, scalar-subquery

Data studio connector returns an error, which I do not understand.
I have done another SQL connector with the same scalar subquery but another source and it works okay.
I do not understand what is difference but if I execute that subquery from the main query it can work. I tested all that thins a lot of times. So I believe I need help

```
DECLARE product_selected STRING;
SET product_selected = (
with total_product_selected as (
with total_product as (
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN ... THEN ...
WHEN ... THEN ...
ELSE 'hostname'
END AS hostname,
array_to_string(array_agg(distinct ifnull(session_product_type, 'null')), '|') as session_product_type
FROM table
group by hostname
)
SELECT session_product_type FROM total_product
WHERE hostname != 'hostname'
AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(hostname, @dssite)
)
SELECT session_product_type FROM total_product_selected
group by session_product_type);

SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE 
REGEXP_CONTAINS(hostname, @dshostname) 
AND
REGEXP_CONTAINS(session_product_type , product_selected) = True
AND event_date between PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_START_DATE) and PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE)
```

I also tried instead of put out separately product_selected just put inside REGEXP_CONTAINS in ().

I managed to get all needed info in standart sql but in DS I got an error like
'
Sorry, we encountered an error and were unable to complete your request.

Error ID: 2bd4a150
'

all of this needed to get string like 'case|case' in regex where clause

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & ideally a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: Please look at the formatted version of your post before you publish. See edit help re block & inline formats for code & quotes, etc.

Comment: Custome Query in DS doesn't support a script that consists of multiple statements. Have you tried it with a single statement using `WITH CTE` clause ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 2 references to "with"

```
WITH total_product
AS (
    SELECT CASE 
            WHEN...
                THEN...
            WHEN...
                THEN...
            ELSE 'hostname'
            END AS hostname
        , array_to_string(array_agg(DISTINCT ifnull(session_product_type, 'null')), '|') AS session_product_type
    FROM TABLE
    GROUP BY hostname
    )
, total_product_selected
AS (
    SELECT session_product_type
    FROM total_product
    WHERE hostname != 'hostname'
        AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(hostname, @dssite)
    )
SELECT session_product_type
FROM total_product_selected
GROUP BY session_product_type;
```

Once you run that final query you cannot keep referring to those CTE's so I guess the following is just a different query unrelated to the CTE's:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(hostname, @dshostname)
    AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(session_product_type, product_selected) = True
    AND event_date BETWEEN PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_START_DATE) AND PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE)
```